# How TLS symmetric encryption works?

Tags: encryption, tls, decryption, key, secret-sharing

After the secret symmetric key is exchanged, how does it look like?

What length (in a production use) is it and what can influence it?

How the key is used to encrypt / decrypt a piece of data? I would be very grateful if u can show the process in both ways with a small theoretical key on a piece of data like "Hello".

Comment: I'm not sure what specifically you want to know. The symmetric encryption method used here is not special to TLS, i.e. common algorithms like AES-GCM etc are used. And the key length is not special either, i.e. 256 bit or similar are today typical in the same way as they are typical for other uses of symmetric encryption. And the exact algorithm and key length are specified by the chosen cipher, which depends on what ciphers the client offers and the server supports.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, in such a case, is somewhere a place where I can find the default (or mostly) supported ones in daily-use browsers? Until now I didn't found a fail into finding a common cipher between the browser and the server.

Comment: You can get [here](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/clients.html) what ciphers the various browsers support.